# Why doesn´t show any data in my select option?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a small app to show some json data from different web services, my code is in http://play.ionic.io/app/44e0a65d2252.
The second url doesn't show noting, what i do wrong?

Thank you very much.

JS:

```
this.showSelectValue = function(mySelect) {
  $http.get("http://www.stcp.pt/pt//itinerarium/callservice.php?action=linedirslist&lcode="+mySelect)
    .success(function (datadir){
      self.direcoes = datadir.records;
      DataStore.direcoes = self.direcoes;
    })
    .error(function(error){
      DataStore.direcoes.length = 0;
    });
```

HTML:

```
<p>Selecione o sentido:</p>
<ion-refresher pulling-text="Pull to refresh..." on-refresh="homeCtl.showSelectValue()">
</ion-refresher>
<select>
   <option ng-repeat="direcao in StopAsCtrl.direcoes" value="{{direcao.dir}}">{{direcao.descr_dir}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your repeated item is:

```
<option ng-repeat="direcao in StopAsCtrl.direcoes" value="{{direcao.dir}}">{{direcao.dir}}</option>
```

You do not have StopAsCtrl defined anywhere. Instead the `direcoes` is also defined in the `homeController`.

You should either change the `in StopAsCtrl.direcoes` to `in homeCtl.direcoes` or define the StopAsCtrl in the `$stateProvider`.

**EDIT based on comment:**

You had still so many problems in your html and js. Here is an example for you that has working parts of your code:

http://play.ionic.io/app/21f5b7454a7d

I will not code the whole app for you, but when more trouble comes your way you can ask a new question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: After i change with your sugestion still not working you can prove in http://play.ionic.io/app/44e0a65d2252